# Imagebutton images in individual divs

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want all the images in an `ImageButton` to be shown in an individual div

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UPEmail" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:DataList  ID="dlImages" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" CellPadding="25" CellSpacing="25">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Imagebutton class="afbeelding" ID="Image1" CommandName='<%# Bind("Naam") %>' ImageUrl='<%# Bind("image", "http://url/Thumbs/{0}") %>' runat="server" style="width:200px; height: 250px; border: 2px grey solid;"  /><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Naam") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                    </asp:DataList>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlType" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlCollection" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlMateriaal" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated based on original post being updated... wrap it in divs.  Below will put a "imageWrapper" class name on every div and a unique "imageWrapper[Naam goes here]" as the ID.  Remove the class/id of the div as desired:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UPEmail" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:DataList  ID="DlImages" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3"
                    CellPadding="25" CellSpacing="25">
                <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="imageWrapper" id='<%# eval("Naam", "imageWrapper{0}") %>'>
                <asp:Imagebutton class="afbeelding" ID="Image1" CommandName='<%# Bind("Naam")%>'
                    ImageUrl = '<%# Bind("image", "http://url/{0}") %>' runat="server"
                    style="width:200px; height: 250px; border: 2px grey solid;z-index: 10;"  />
                    </div><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Naam") %>'></asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                </asp:DataList>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlType" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlCollection"
                EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlMateriaal"
                EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just wrap 1 div around all the images

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, no, it wouldn't.  Based on your code, it looks like you may have the images inside a repeater?  You could use the same string formatting to put an individual id on these.

Are these inside a repeater or are you manually adding each?

Comment: They are inside a repeater

Comment: If the <div> tags are inside a repeater, they will also repeat.  I wouldn't use individual ID's, only use a class if necessary (or just leave the <div> tag entirely without any attributes, unless needed).

Comment: The thing is, i want the images to be called in either css or js

Comment: it gives me an error " A call to Bind must be assigned to a property of a control inside a template"

Comment: Ah, it probably needs an Eval instead of a bind.

Comment: Nice, didn't even see that. Well let's try it

Answer (score 1):

you can use CSS `style="display:block"`

So change your code as

```
<asp:Imagebutton class="afbeelding" ID="Image1" CommandName='<%# Bind("Naam") %>' ImageUrl='<%# Bind("image", "url/Thumbs/{0}") %>' runat="server" style="display:block;width:200px; height: 250px; border: 2px grey solid;"  />
```

Read more http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: No I want all the images to be shown in individual divs..
So if you open the source code in the online website you'll see every picture being surrounded by its on div